# enterprise library 3.1 - if one listener is failed then subsequent listener will be never executed

Tags: enterprise-library

I am using Msmqdistributor service of Enterprise Library 3.1 to distribute logs from various application.I have defined multiple listeners in categorySources/specialSources, but if one listener is failed than subsequent listeners will be never executed.

Following is my config code.

```
<specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="Warning" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Database Listener A" />          
          <add name="Custom Trace Listener A" />
          <add name="Custom Trace Listener B" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="Warning" name="Unprocessed Category" />        
      <errors switchValue="Warning" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings"/>        
</specialSources>
```

If I am specifying wrong connection string for **Database Listener A** then it will be failed to insert logs in database. But it also stops the jobs of next **Custom Trace Listener A and Custom Trace Listener B**.So here Custom Trace Listener A and Custom Trace Listener B will be never executed if **Database Listener A** is failed.

Anybody can help please ?

Thanks
Mitesh Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior seems to be "by design".  See the answer for [Microsoft Enterprise Library 4.1 Logging Fails on Windows XP SP3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784241/microsoft-enterprise-library-4-1-logging-fails-on-windows-xp-sp3/4790437#4790437).

Of course, this doesn't really help you.  One workaround would be to attach one listener to a category.  So for your 3 listeners you could add 3 categories.  This will work but is not particularly elegant.

Since you indicate that you are using 2 custom trace listeners another approach to mitigate the issue would be to code the custom trace listeners to swallow any exceptions (not usually a good idea, though).  You could also order your trace listeners from least likely to fail to most likely to fail.  E.g. Database > Event Log > Flat File.  In your scenario place the custom trace listeners before the database trace listener.

It is also good practice to add a trace listener to the errors category.  Not sure if you have that in your app or not (but the posted config doesn't).

Comment: Hi Tuzo, Thanks for your prompt reply. But in my current requirement, I want to suppress any exception in Listener and continue with the subsequent Listeners.I could not swallow an exception in Database Listener, because it is in-built listener. Also I can specify listeners in <errors/> of <specialSources> for any exception but, here also the same situation.

Comment: @user988917: Yes, I know you can't suppress in Database Listener; that's why I suggest to put it last.  You could create your own Database Listener from the EL source and then not throw in there.  Of course, you are probably going to want to capture and log that failure somehow so you know there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks again Tuzo. But I want for all listener, if any error comes it will be suppressed. I have got the solution to achieve it by inheriting base classes of LogSource and LogWriter